# Why is SDL so slow and how can I get it to run faster?

Tags: performance, graphics, 2d, sdl

I have the following test setup:

- 1024 * 768 screen surface created with SDL_HWSURFACE
- The main loop consists only of SDL_Flip() and a simple FPS counter

The problem is:

I am only getting around 1000 FPS with this. Which is really really low when you consider that you do not even draw anything!

The FPS drop really fast when I continue on to blitting rather large surfaces on the screen as well.

What I wanted to do:

A pixel-per-pixel effects/physics destructible terrain/objects game.

- Why is SDL so slow? (I have played around for three days with the small example test and eliminated every possible mistake I could have made, so I am quite sure that it actually is SDL's fault)
- Are there any secret tricks to get it to run faster?
- **Are there other 2D APIs which provide easy and rather fast single-pixel access?**

Comment: FPS is a non-linear performance metric.  Try (milli)seconds per frame instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pixel access it's very slow in hardware surfaces (it's a hardware limit, not a sdl limit).

You can try [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/features.php) that it's OpenGL accelerated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that calling SDL_HWSURFACE won't always result in the use of the hardware depending on your graphical card.